# copy/paste not working in ubuntu22

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, directory, dual-boot, readonly

just copied some files from /home/user/Downloads directory and tried pasting into ntfs filesystem,and got this way
"could not paste files;permissions do not allow to paste files in this directory"

OS:UBUNTU 22LTS

Comment: What directory are you pasting to? Please edit your question and add this info. This is not a live support website, there are volunteers who answer in their spare time. There's no need to rush or expect answers right away.

Comment: What version/flavour of Ubuntu are you running: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS, Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS or Ubuntu Core 22 or some other version/flavour?

Comment: Copying from Filesystem of Linux(ubuntu22LTS) to ntfs filesystem,Incase someone is free they will respond and I knew it,Dont know why you are in impression that I am in rush.

Comment: @sudodus its Ubuntu22LTS Desktop

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks for your response anyway

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski its casual question,told the problem,but yes this forum will respond for the issue posted.

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question and add more details there. We have no idea what error you get, what tools you use to copy and paste, not even what directory you are getting the error about. It sounds like you are simply trying to copy a file into a directory you do not have permission to write to. But we can't know because you haven't told us anything.

Comment: @terdon just copied some files from /home/user/Downloads directory and tried pasting into ntfs filesystem,and got this way "could not paste files;permissions do not allow to paste files in this directory"

Comment: Yes, please ***EDIT*** your question and add all of this information there. We need to know all this to be able to help you. Also show is the output of running `mount | grep ntfs` in a terminal so we can see how this ntfs system has been mounted.

Comment: root@user-laptop:/home/user# mount | grep ntfs
root@user-laptop:/home/user# 

no output@terdon

Comment: initially,tried copying files into ntfs directory through command line but got an output cannot create regular file: read only filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is one common reason why the NTFS file system is read-only

- **The NTFS file system is 'dirty' due to Fast Startup in Windows**, and Linux automount refuses to mount read/write to avoid causing damage. See [this AskUbuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867202/internal-hard-drive-mounting-as-read-only/867206#867206) and a link from there to a tutorial how to turn off Fast Startup.

  If the Windows system that made the file system 'dirty' is not available, it is recommended to use some other Windows system to repair the file system. There is good old `chkdsk` and there are tools with graphical user interfaces for this task.
- **Some other reason, even when NTFS is good. In this case you can unmount and mount again** to set suitable ownership and/or permissions. There is a detailed description at [this AskUbuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).